# vue модальное окно ошибка с props

Tags: javascript, properties, vue.js

Vue компонент модального окна.
При вызове метода savePos

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template',
  props: ['show'],
  methods: {
    savePost: function () {
      // Insert AJAX call here...
      this.show = false;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showModal: false
  }
});
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
vue2.js:513 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "show" 
(found in component <modal>)
```

Пробовал так:

```
var temp = this.show; 
temp = false;
```

Тоже не работает.
Не пойму, как использовать мутированные сойства.

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя изменять props компонента в нем самом
Можно либо state modal (show | hidden) держать в глобальном state (шина, vuex) либо генерировать событие через $emit внутри modal, ловить его в родителе и там менять state.